# Bitcoin Core Make error

Tags: c++11, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am new to bitcoin core development. I have created a clone using bitcoin core version v0.15.0rc3 on a mac os high sierra 10.13.2. I am have installed all dependencies and am able to run the autogen.sh and configure with no errors. However, when I run make I am getting the following error.

```
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_server_a-miner.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

You can see the full error in pastebin https://pastebin.com/M7tNaiMM

I have been trying to resolve the issue for 2 days and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the Const not being labelled outside of the function parameters. Found the issue resolution on github but looks like they have not added the change to bitcoin core code yet.

update the miner.h file and the txmempool.h file with const

https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/commit/1ec0c0a01c316146434642ab2f14a7367306dbec

Comment: Great solution ! Thank you. Adding the "const" keyword where needed solves this.